# How do I rewire my kitchen ceiling light?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, light

I'm trying to install a new light in my kitchen but I have six wires coming out of the ceiling but I have no idea which wires are which can you guys help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your "before" picture? OK, lesson learned! ;)

Comment: Or this? [What do I do with 6 wires going into a light socket?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/286874/what-do-i-do-with-6-wires-going-into-a-light-socket)

Answer (score 2):

Picture is good.

That is a simple switch loop and the black loose wire goes the black of the light, and the white from the light goes to the two wires that seem brown, but at one time were white.

The white attached to the blacks is for the hot to the switch(it should have black or red marking on it), the loose black is the switch hot.

One cable is from power, one cable carries power to something else, and the third cable is from the switch.

Comment: I'm sure you realize that this is a manifold duplicate and should be closed as such. I'd swear that exact photo exists already.

Comment: What an amazing memory!